# After Permutation Puzzles

Tags: permutations, book-recommendation

Have been reading "Permutation Puzzles" of Jamie Mulholland.  What can I read after this, which do not involve games, but actual small problems in industry?

Comment: I would recommend "Oval Track and Other Permutation Puzzles" by 
John O. Kiltinen

Comment: I think that is still about games, rather than uses of permutations beyond games.

Comment: What kind of engineering application are you thinking of?

Comment: Biology or medicine perhaps.